# Array to key value pair (Hash)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, key-value

```
>> description

=> [" name=\"margin-top\" content=\"1\" />\r\n", " name=\"oreintation\" content=\"horizontal\" />\r\n", " name=\"paper-height\" content=\"6\" />\r\n", " name=\"paper-width\" content=\"5\" />\r\n", " name=\"margin-left\" content=\"3\" />\r\n"]
```

`description` is of type `array`

I need `key` as `margin-top` value `1`. 
I need `key` as `oreintation` value `oreintation` and so on, how to get this done?

Comment: i'm not the downvoter, but i suspect it's because this question is basically, here's the input, here's my required output, write the code for me. you need to show what you've tried

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
result = {}
description.each{|val|
 result[val.split("\"")[1]] = val.split("\"")[3]
}
result # contains expected hash
```